# what is the difference between "def on_data(self, data):" and "def on_status(self, status):" in tweepy streamListener?

Tags: python, nlp, web-crawler, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

what is the difference between "def on_data(self, data):"  and "def on_status(self, status):" in tweepy streamListener ?

hi, in the [tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html)
they use **def on_status** for streaming:

```
import tweepy
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
    print(status.text)
```

But [this tutorial](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/) use **def on_data** for streaming:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class MyListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
```

what is the difference?

Comment: Just a note, when a field says `enter link description here` you are asked to actually enter something there and not just leave the default text ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Read the first link. The "difference" is that one happens before the other.

> The `on_data` method of Tweepy’s StreamListener conveniently passes data from statuses to the `on_status` method.